# How do browsers cache PAC files?

Tags: proxy, firefox, google-chrome, pac

How do browsers and other applications cache PAC files? If I'm serving a PAC file and update the configuration (e.g. add or remove a domain that should go through the proxy), when will different browsers recognize the updated configuration? Is there anything I can do on the PAC file server to flush the cache?

How long do PAC files stay in a browser cache? What will trigger the cache to be cleared?

I have found this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-disable-automatic-proxy-caching-in-internet-explorer-92735c9c-8a26-d0d8-7f8a-1b46595cbaba for IE, but not finding any information for Chrome/Firefox/Edge

Comment: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/net/docs/proxy.md This have many answers about Chrome.